# how to pass array through javascript to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i am having **one array in javascript** named as **checkboxarray** which contain some elements which is dynamic.

now i want to pass this **array to controller** through java script.

my **controller name** is **Test** and **action name** is **Questionbank.**

can any one tell me how to pass this **array to controller**?

I have tried through ajax but value is coming null at controller.

Comment: Please include the relevant code. Otherwise debugging it is job for a crystal ball, not a programmer. :-)

Comment: you can use ajax to send array in the data parameter

Comment: can u show me thorugh code for how to passthroguh ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` when you posting data to pass arry of objects to controller.

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'Test/Questionbank',
    data: JSON.stringify({checkboxarray  : checkboxarray }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function () { alert('error');}
});
```

Please refer following post for more information.

[Pass Complex JavaScript Object to MVC Controller](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2014/01/pass-complex-javascript-object-to-mvc.html)

It illustrates how we can pass complex javascript objects to MVC controller.

Thanks !